# Render partial after ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am creating a form where if the user enters in an URL, my code will return an image url.
When the result is successful, I want to update the partial that displays the image without reloading the page

in my controller

```
  def receive_url
    img_path = ProcessUrl.new.parse_url(params[:submitted_url])
  end
```

in my view

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag({controller: "get_url", action: "receive_url"}, method: :post, remote: true) do %>
    <%= label_tag "Enter Url" %>
    <%= text_field_tag "submitted_url", nil, placeholder: 'Enter search url...'%>
    <%= button_tag "Publish", class: 'button', data: { disable_with: "Please wait.." } %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= render :partial => 'image', locals: { stored_url: @stored_url } %>
```

in my partial _image.html.erb

```
<div>
  <% if @stored_url != nil %>
    <a href="<%= @stored_url %>" > 
      <div id="background_image" style="height: 300px; width: auto; background-image: url(<%= @stored_url %>); background-repeat: no-repeat"></div>
    </a>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

what do I need to do in my controller to pass in `@stored_url`

Comment: Please tell us what version of Rails you have. As it is quite easy to do with Rails 7 Turbo. If your Rails app is older, do you plan to use Jquery or Javascript ? Also why your partial has an instance variable `@stored_url` as you pass the local `stored_url` in your view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this answer, I'm assuming your routes are correctly set. I'm also assuming you have jquery. If not, i'll adapt the answer to plain javascript syntax.

```rb
<%= render :partial => 'image', locals: { stored_url: @stored_url } %>
```

The line above in your view will only render on page load. To have it update after submitting a link to the `receive_url` endpoint, we'll have to use some javascript. In traditional rails way, this is handled by a `*.js.erb` file.

Before we do that, lets adjust the view and partial slightly:

**index.html.erb:**

```rb
<div>
  <%= form_tag({controller: "get_url", action: "receive_url"}, method: :post, remote: true) do %>
    <%= label_tag "Enter Url" %>
    <%= text_field_tag "submitted_url", nil, placeholder: 'Enter search url...'%>
    <%= button_tag "Publish", class: 'button', data: { disable_with: "Please wait.." } %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div id="image_section">
<%= render :partial => 'image', locals: { stored_url: @stored_url } %>
</div>
```

The view is updated so we have a `div` with and `id`. We can use that id as a reference for our `js.erb` file where to update the view.

**_image.html.erb:**

```rb
  <% if @stored_url != nil %>
    <a href="<%= @stored_url %>" > 
      <div id="background_image" style="height: 300px; width: auto; background-image: url(<%= @stored_url %>); background-repeat: no-repeat"></div>
    </a>
  <% end %>
```

In the partial, we just got rid of the `div` tag, since it is now present in the view.

Our controller also needs to be adjusted. we want to tell rails we'll answer the call with some javascript (`js.erb`), and we want to have the variable `@stored_url` available in our partial:

**controller:**

```rb
    def receive_url
      img_path = ProcessUrl.new.parse_url(params[:submitted_url])

      #fill in our stored_url
      @stored_url = <YOUR LOGIC TO GET THE URL>
      #tell rails we would like to respond with js
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
      end
    end
```

Finally, we need to create a `receive_url.js.erb` file in our view map.
This javascript function will be called after our request to `receive_url` is processed. Notice that the name of this file is the same as our endpoint.

**receive_url.js.erb:**

```js
$("#partial_image_section").html("<%= j (render 'image') %>");
```

It does the following: First, it searches for an element with `id` equal to `partial_image_section`. Secondly, it replaces its inner html with `render 'image'`. The `render` function will rerender our partial, resulting in a new image.

Comment: I have a question.  why is the .js.erb file using `#partial_image_section` when the id is `id='image_section'`.  Anyways i changed it to `$("#image_section").html("<%= j (render 'image') %>");`but it still doesnt work.

I think I included jquery the right way but I am not sure.  I followed some instructions online to do that

Comment: i adjusted the answer to `image` . You do have a `_image.html.erb` file in the view folder right? And what error do you get with `render 'image'`?

Comment: if you don't got jquery, you can replace `$("#partial_image_section").html("<%= j (render 'image') %>");` with `Document.getElementById("partial_image_section").innerHTML ="<%= j (render 'image') %>"; `

Comment: nevermind, i was being stupid.  I did not install jquery the right way.  your original solution worked after a bit of modification!  thank you so much!!!

Comment: you're welcome! Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your issue. Happy coding!